# How to Perform Coordinate Constrained Clustering

Tags: machine-learning, clustering

Constrained Clustering typically refers to problems where certain pairs need to be included in or excluded from the same cluster.

However the problem I'm dealing with has a constraint on where the **center** of my clusters can be located.

[image]

Suppose we're working on a 2D plane. We have a rectangular circuit surrounded by a number of red points. We'd like to find a clustering algorithm, to group these red points into N clusters, such that in the **final** output the centroids for all clusters will fall in the circuit region.

I've considered running a large number of k-means iterations until this constraint is satisfied,  but I'd like to ask if there's a more "reliable" approach.